# Is Google Account required for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to write a simple app to get PUSH Notifications.
I used GCM which uses Google Play Services to get information.

My questions is - to access GCM, is Google Account required or not?
Can i use another email account to identify device?
Is there any other way to get push notification for another email account or device?

Comment: Yes, Google account is required.You need to obtain Sender_Id and Application_Id form Google Developer Console by logging into your Google account.

Comment: you can find your answser [here]


  [here]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336808/is-it-possible-to-use-gcm-without-google-account-and-google-play-services-on-the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [GCM Characteristics](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

> It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0
>   devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their
>   mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices
>   running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

If your app is supporting pre-3.0 devices, so **yes**, Google Account is required and you need to add this permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in other answers, the GCM documentation states that a Google Account is required on the device for Android versions older than 4.0.4.

However, in the [following post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/ecG-RfH-Aso) from the android-gcm Google group, a Google developer claims that if you are using the latest version of Google Play Services, you don't need a Google Account on the device even for older devices (Froyo and Gingerbread).

> Some background:  Froyo and Gingerbread registration is implemented in
>   GoogleServicesFramework, using the Google account for registration.
>   This has resulted in a lot of auth errors for people where the account
>   was not in a good state.
>
> Starting with ICS, GCM doesn't depend or uses the Google account - you
>   can use it before you add an account or without any accounts.
>
> **The "Play Services" update is implementing the new scheme on all
>   devices** - but it seems a small number of devices have problems with
>   this, we're investigating - but the numbers are far lower than those
>   with the old scheme.
>
> If you want to use the code in GSF, for Froyo and Gingerbread - you
>   need to use the previous library, which sets package name explicitly.
>   The new library in GCM is using the new registration code.
>
> The actual connection to google is following the same path - we're
>   gradually (and slowly) moving devices to the new code in play
>   services.

I haven't tested it, so I can't say if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes whenever you need to use GCM  Google account is required.

Because when you have logged in your account at that time **Sender_Id and Application_Id** in your url browser. So you will get it through Google Developer Console and use in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google account is required.You need to obtain Sender_Id and Application_Id form Google Developer Console by logging into your Google account.

Comment: For development - yes. For end-users - not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Google account login is no longer needed for `GCM` to work. So you no need the `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` permission.

If you are using `GCM` `API` with `InstanceID (GCM 3.0)` or `GoogleCloudMessaging.register(GCM 2.0)` then there is no need to configure Google account on any Android version and no need to give `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` Permission.

But if you are using the deprecated library `GCMRegistrar.register`, you still need a Google Account on older versions