# Is a Google Play account needed to *receive* push notifications?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a user who is using an app. My app sends push notifications for certain events. This particular user does not have a Google Play subscription -he sideloaded my app.

When the app starts, the app is able to generate a push token for his device. However when my server sends a push, his device does not get it.

I've searched around, and I've seen threads which talk about requiring a Google account for "sending" a push - but my question is for receiving. The fact that it is able to "generate" a token during registration is confusing, if Google was planning not to route GCM messages to the device.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an old question from GCM but it says you do need an account on some devices. I dont think it has changed for FCM either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605907/is-google-account-required-for-gcm-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Thanks that is the thread I read before I posted. It's referring to being able to send notifications but doesn't really talk about receiving. I'm curious why a token is generated by the service if it won't be routed.

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I'm a bit confused. By "*This particular user does not have a Google Play subscription -he sideloaded my app.*", do you mean that the device has no Google Play Services?

Comment: Hi Al, that is correct. No google play services.

Comment: then yes, no google play services means no push notifications

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept - also if you have any insights into why a token is generated on push registration if the device does not have play services would be helpful too (though not necessary)