# meteor cordova app push notifications (FCM/GCM)

Tags: cordova, meteor, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-fcm

I tried to implement push notifications mainly for the hybrid android app I build with meteor.
Tried the raix:push atmosphere package one will easily find on google as first reference on google. 
After it seemed not to work we also tried OneSignal as a complete solution.

In the end I tried to set up FCM without any wrapper around it.
And then I realized that google play services is required in order to use FCM at all.

**Now our Question is:**

We have an App which we won't distribute via Google Play Store.
Is it still possible to use Google Play Services to use push notifications (FCM/GCM) ?

Any further hints and explanations are welcome.

best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use GCM without Google account AND Google Play Services on the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336808/is-it-possible-to-use-gcm-without-google-account-and-google-play-services-on-the)

Comment: I was dumb not including google-services.json and the other settings to build.gradle. For everyone using meteors build option to build a cordova app. You need to open your android project you build with "meteor build" with android studio and follow the steps given in "Notifications" on https://console.firebase.google.com/.