# What are the options for using Meteor JS to implement Android push notification

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile, push-notification, onesignal

I am a newbie to Meteor JS so please pardon me if my question is sort of stupid. I've been struggling to find the right way to implement push notification on Android with Meteor JS. It seems like the options out there are surprisingly limited. I've looked into Raix Push, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

I was wondering if anyone has found a way that still works today to successfully implement push notification on a Meteor JS application (whether through OneSignal SDK, Raix or something else)? If so, can you please be so kind to tell me what the method is, so at least I have a general direction to follow?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Meteor on one of my bigger projects and have successfully implemented Push Notifications.

I used Raix/Push package combined with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

There are plenty options like you mentioned yourself but for me the mentioned one was the best.

RAIX/Push only does the sending of push messages to your cloude service (e.g. FCM) and does the token management. But you need to configure the FCM service yourself so it knows, who is a client, who do I send a push notification to..

When you build a APK with Meteor you will get an Android Project which is an Cordova Enviornment which runs your Meteor Application.

You need to follow the steps given in your FCM console (console.firebase.google.com) and bind in some custom data and manipulate gradle and xml files here and there. (You will find detailed explanations there).

**edit**

here you can see my old post explaining my own mistakes done with FCM/GCM and raix/push

[meteor cordova app push notifications (FCM/GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019357/meteor-cordova-app-push-notifications-fcm-gcm)